# Frequency of letters - disproportionately high ratio

Tags: c

This project computes the average letter frequency of letters in a book - for some reason, A,B, and Z are getting drastically bigger numbers - in the billions. Am I missing something here? I feel like there is no error, but the resulting code is wrong. `argv[1]` is the book file and `argv[2]` is the new file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define NUM_LETTERS 26

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    FILE *fp,*fp2;
    int ch, totalcounter = 0, i;
    int letters[25];
    double letterfrequency[25];
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0; i<NUM_LETTERS; i++)
    {
        letters[i] = 0;
        letterfrequency[i] = 0.0;
    }
    printf("Opening: %s", argv[1]);
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(!fp)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }
    while((ch=fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        ch = toupper(ch);
        if('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z')
        {
            ch -= 65;
            letters[ch]++;
            totalcounter++;
        }
    }

    fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    for(i=0; i<NUM_LETTERS; i++)
    {
        letterfrequency[i] = (double)letters[i]/totalcounter;
    }
    for(i=0; i<NUM_LETTERS; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp2, "\n%c: Times used: %10d\tFrequency Used: %20.20lf", i+65, letters[i], letterfrequency[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which alphabet only has 25 letters?  You're writing out of bounds of your arrays, so anything goes.

Comment: A quick and dirty test file containing just the letters a through z segfaults. Your code needs some work.

Comment: You used character constants for the range-check, but why this: `ch -= 65;`? Don't use magic numbers! And why not simply use `isalpha` for the check?

Comment: love the fact you define "#define NUM_LETTERS 26" and then hard code the incorrect '25' !

Comment: The `ch -= 65` refers to capital A being ASCII number 65. So subtracting that value is to convert the ASCII value to an index between 0-25 to index into the array.

Comment: @David: yes, but the better way of writing it is `ch -= 'A';`.

Comment: Thank you.. I was set in the mindset that the 25 meant 0-25(aka 26). I got mixed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you are trying to squeeze the counts for 26 letters into space reserved for 25.  This does not lead to happiness.

This is a minor cleanup of your code.  Apart from changing the array sizes to `NUM_LETTERS`, it reports the usage better, checks that the output file is opened, uses `isalpha()` to check for letters, and converts from upper-case to offset by subtracting `'A'` rather than `65`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NUM_LETTERS 26

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp, *fp2;
    int ch, totalcounter = 0, i;
    int letters[NUM_LETTERS];
    double letterfrequency[NUM_LETTERS];

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s infile outfile\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_LETTERS; i++)
    {
        letters[i] = 0;
        letterfrequency[i] = 0.0;
    }

    printf("Opening: %s\n", argv[1]);
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if (isalpha(ch))
        {
            ch = toupper(ch) - 'A';
            letters[ch]++;
            totalcounter++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_LETTERS; i++)
    {
        letterfrequency[i] = (double)letters[i] / totalcounter;
    }

    printf("Opening: %s\n", argv[2]);
    fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (!fp)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_LETTERS; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp2, "%c: Times used: %10d\tFrequency Used: %20.20lf\n", i + 65, letters[i], letterfrequency[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Example output (on the source code above — `fq97.c`):

```
Opening: fq97.c
Opening: /dev/stdout
A: Times used:         17   Frequency Used: 0.02956521739130434784
B: Times used:          3   Frequency Used: 0.00521739130434782650
C: Times used:         26   Frequency Used: 0.04521739130434782733
D: Times used:         13   Frequency Used: 0.02260869565217391366
E: Times used:         78   Frequency Used: 0.13565217391304348893
F: Times used:         41   Frequency Used: 0.07130434782608695288
G: Times used:         13   Frequency Used: 0.02260869565217391366
H: Times used:         13   Frequency Used: 0.02260869565217391366
I: Times used:         50   Frequency Used: 0.08695652173913043237
J: Times used:          0   Frequency Used: 0.00000000000000000000
K: Times used:          0   Frequency Used: 0.00000000000000000000
L: Times used:         33   Frequency Used: 0.05739130434782608453
M: Times used:          8   Frequency Used: 0.01391304347826087008
N: Times used:         43   Frequency Used: 0.07478260869565217517
O: Times used:         25   Frequency Used: 0.04347826086956521618
P: Times used:         26   Frequency Used: 0.04521739130434782733
Q: Times used:          5   Frequency Used: 0.00869565217391304358
R: Times used:         52   Frequency Used: 0.09043478260869565466
S: Times used:         25   Frequency Used: 0.04347826086956521618
T: Times used:         61   Frequency Used: 0.10608695652173913415
U: Times used:         26   Frequency Used: 0.04521739130434782733
V: Times used:          6   Frequency Used: 0.01043478260869565299
W: Times used:          2   Frequency Used: 0.00347826086956521752
X: Times used:          3   Frequency Used: 0.00521739130434782650
Y: Times used:          6   Frequency Used: 0.01043478260869565299
Z: Times used:          0   Frequency Used: 0.00000000000000000000
```